# duplicates being created in todo list app

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a todo list where when the user clicks the checkbox "complete" that is next to the todo item, it appears in the complete component however there is a duplicate of that item that is being added as well and i am also having an issue trying to have the checkbox not appear in the completed component...
When a user creates a new todo it appears in the active component first and it has a checkbox next to it called completed and when the user clicks the checkbox it appears in the completed component

```
import React from 'react';
import Active from './Components/Active';
import Completed from './Components/Completed';
import Todoform from './Components/Todoform';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {

state = {
  items: [],
  task: '',
  id: 0,
  completedItems: []
}

handleInput = (event) => {
this.setState({
  task: event.target.value
})
}

handleSubmit = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault()

   const newTask = {
  id: this.state.id,
  title: this.state.task
}

const updatedItems = [...this.state.items, newTask]
 this.setState({
  items: updatedItems,
  task: '',
  id: this.state.id + 1
})
}

 handleComplete = (newTask) => {
    this.setState({completedItems: [...this.state.items, newTask]})
    //console.log(this.state.items)
}


 render() {
return (
  <div id="main-content">
    <h1>Task Lister</h1>
    <Todoform
    handleChange={this.handleInput}
    handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
    task={this.state.task}
    />
    <Active
    items={this.state.items}
    handleComplete={this.handleComplete}
    />
    <Completed
    completedItems={this.state.completedItems}
    />
  </div>
)

   }
 }

export default App;


 import React from 'react'

 class Todo extends React.Component{

     state = {
       checked: false
     }

handleCheck = () => {
  this.setState({
  checked: !this.state.checked
  })
}

handleClick = () => {
   this.props.handlecompletedList(this.props.title)
 }

 render(){
    const { title } = this.props

   return (
      <div className="ui checked checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.handleCheck} 
      onClick={this.handleClick}/>
      <label>Completed {title}</label>
      </div>
     )

      }

   }
 export default Todo;

import React from 'react'
import Todo from './Todo'

 const Active = (props) => {

 const { items, handleComplete } = props


  return(
     <div id="activeList">
     <h2 className="position">Active</h2>
     <ul id="tasks">
       {
        items.map(item => {
          return(
            <Todo key={item.id} handlecompletedList={handleComplete}  title={item.title}/>
          )
        })
      }
  </ul>
</div>

  )
}
  export default Active;

 import React from 'react'
 import Todo from './Todo'

  const Completed = (props) => {

  const { completedItems } = props

    return(
       <div id="completedList">
       <h2 className="position">Completed</h2>
       <ul id="tasks">
     {
        completedItems.map(item => {
         return(
            <Todo key={item.id} title={item.title}/>
         )
       })
     }
     </ul>
   </div>

  )
 }
export default Completed

  import React from 'react';

  class Todoform  extends React.Component {

  render(){
const {task, handleChange, handleSubmit} = this.props;
return(

  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <label>Task description:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="description" value={task} onChange={handleChange}/>
    <button>Create New Task</button>
  </form>

)

  }

}
export default Todoform;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide the checkbox next to completed items you need to use `Conditional Rendering`. An example would be to add a prop `IsCompleted` to your component and use it when rendering html like this:

```
{this.props.isCompleted &&
    <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={this.state.checked}
        onChange={this.handleCheck}
        onClick={this.handleClick}/>
}
```

The duplicate item issue is probably because you use `this.state.items` in your `handleComplete` method instead of using `this.state.completedItems` if this is not the issue, would you mind sharing the code for the `Todoform` component as well?

**EDIT:** The item duplicates because when the `handleComplete` is called it copies `this.state.items` to the list and adds the one that you clicked on.
You should use `this.state.completedItems` in the `handleComplete`, also you are currently only sending and appending the title in the `handleComplete` method, you should be appending an object that has a title. The solution would be to update your `handleClick` method to this and update `handleComplete` to use `this.state.completedItems`:

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.props.handlecompletedList({
        title: this.props.title
    });
};
```

Comment: when I used this.state.completedItems, it was coming up empty and yes ill share the todo form

Comment: I added the todo form in the question

Comment: just for some clarification for the conditional rendering should I set state for isCompleted, like if the check box is checked then isCompleted is true or something like that?

Comment: @hannah I was thinking about adding it like a prop to the `Todo` component and set it to true when creating elements in the `Completed` component

Comment: I tried the solution that you just gave me and it works, only issue is that even when I uncheck the box it still gets put into the completed component

Comment: @hannah yeah, you should write separate logic to remove it when the unchecking happens